# how to get the index of QList according to QSignalMapper

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

I have `QList` of `QPushButton`'s and `QSignalMapper` to recognize which button is pushed.
So I did something like that (my project is very big, so I cut just the lines needed to the question)

```
QList<QPushButton*> Buttons;
QList <QLabel*> LabelList1;
QList <QLabel*> LabelList2;
QList <QLabel*> LabelList3;
QList <QLabel*> LabelList4;
QSignalMapper *ButtonsMapper;
ButtonsMapper= new QSignalMapper(this);
connect(ButtonsMapper, SIGNAL(mapped(int)),this,SIGNAL(ButtonsClicked(int)));
connect(this, SIGNAL(ButtonsClicked(int)),this,SLOT(deleteButton(int)));

Buttons.append(new QPushButton(tr("0")));//first button 
LabelList1.append(new QLabel(tr("0")));
LabelList2.append(new QLabel(tr("0")));
LabelList3.append(new QLabel(tr("0")));
LabelList4.append(new QLabel(tr("0")));
QPushButton * pb1 = Buttons.last();//pointer to the last button
connect(pb1, SIGNAL(clicked()), ButtonsMapper, SLOT(map()));
ButtonsMapper->setMapping(pb1,0);

Buttons.append(new QPushButton(tr("1")));//second button
LabelList1.append(new QLabel(tr("1")));
LabelList2.append(new QLabel(tr("1")));
LabelList3.append(new QLabel(tr("1")));
LabelList4.append(new QLabel(tr("1"))); 
QPushButton * pb2 = Buttons.last();//pointer to the last button
connect(pb2, SIGNAL(clicked()), ButtonsMapper, SLOT(map()));
ButtonsMapper->setMapping(pb2,1);
```

and the function `deleteButton` supposed to delete the button was pressed. If I do something like that

```
void myclass::deleteButton(int i){ 
   delete (Buttons.takeAt(i));
   delete ( LabelList1.takeAt(i));
   delete ( LabelList2.takeAt(i));
   delete( LabelList3.takeAt(i));
   delete( LabelList4.takeAt(i));
    }
```

that function can lead to `index out of range` error, if I delete the first button, and then I press on the second button, the function `Buttons.takeAt(i)` point to not exist button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theoretically, you could keep a pointer to the signal mapper around, and remap the indexes after deletion.

```
void myclass::deleteButton(int i){
    delete (Buttons.takeAt(i));
    for(int i = 0; i < Buttons.size(); ++i) {
        ButtonsMapper->setMapping(Buttons[i], i);
    }
}
```

Comment: its good if i have 1 QList, but i have at least 8 QList that i supposed to delete evrytime...

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you some modifiacation of your code:

```
QMap<QPushButton*,int> Buttons;
QSignalMapper *ButtonsMapper;
ButtonsMapper= new QSignalMapper(this);
connect(ButtonsMapper, SIGNAL(mapped(int)),this,SIGNAL(ButtonsClicked(int)));
connect(this, SIGNAL(ButtonsClicked(int)),this,SLOT(deleteButton(int)));

Buttons.insert (new QPushButton(tr("0")),0);//first button 
QPushButton * pb1 = Buttons.last();//pointer to the last button
connect(pb1, SIGNAL(clicked()), ButtonsMapper, SLOT(map()));
ButtonsMapper->setMapping(pb1,0);

Buttons.insert (new QPushButton(tr("1")),1);//second button 
QPushButton * pb2 = Buttons.last();//pointer to the last button
connect(pb2, SIGNAL(clicked()), ButtonsMapper, SLOT(map()));
ButtonsMapper->setMapping(pb2,1);

void myclass::deleteButton(int i){
    if (Buttons.contains(i))
    delete (Buttons[i]);  
}
```

Comment: QMap is not fit to my project, i need the array to be organized, without skipping ....

Comment: something like ,int index = Buttons.indexOf(ButtonsMapper->mapping(i)); which not work

Comment: Why do you need list for? If you don't need it to anything except deleting after clicking, you may use mapping with `QObject *` instead.

Comment: i need list for few reasons ,delete,insert, and few loop by some indexes . actually i think i solved this problem, but i cant answer here because i'm new user.... void myclass::deleteButton(int i){
        int index = Buttons.indexOf((QPushButton*)ButtonsMapper->mapping(i));
        delete (Buttons.takeAt(index));

Comment: this solution dont work correct if there is no PushBoton exemplar in QList

Answer (score 0):

Instead of mapping QPushButton to index (`int`) you could map it to `QWidget *`.

```
- ButtonsMapper->setMapping(pb1,0);
+ ButtonsMapper->setMapping(pb1, pb1);
```

Then slot also will change

```
void myclass::deleteButton(QWidget * widget){
    Buttons.removeOne(widget);
    delete widget;  
}
```

Comment: it's good but not for my project,  because that i have 8 QList , and i want to delete evry time one cell from evryone according to QPushButton is pushed... i'm edit my question , so you could understand that.... tnx